# jQuery collapsing faded divs and expanding animation problem

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, opacity, fade

I'm trying to animate an image to the full width and height of a div it works with the top left image as i'd expect but the others it moves the image to the top left and then animates it

[Here's a link to my jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3WqB3/)

Is there a way to fade the siblings out and then animate the image from its current position?

Thanks

**SOLUTION**

To get my desired effect which works in all browsers I did this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ChiBlaaa/BdSqj/)

Thanks to iWasRobbed for helping with the solution

Comment: The img src in your sample seems to be wrong.

Comment: @Dogbert I didn't link the images - I just put widths and heights so you could see what i was trying to accomplish

Comment: What you're trying to accomplish is harder than you might think.

Comment: Ah. I guess you were using Chrome to test. The jsfiddle example doesn't do anything on FF.

Comment: You could split it into 4 divs, each with a different align. I noticed when I have two different aligns in the same div the fade effect breaks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It definitely is possible, just not with the `fadeIn` or `fadeOut` functions.  Instead, you have to animate opacity on absolutely positioned elements.  If you try and use `fadeIn` or `fadeOut` then it does nothing.

Here is a jfiddle version with jQuery 1.5.0 where it works (added Orbling's images for Firefox users who can't see a broken image symbol): http://jsfiddle.net/iwasrobbed/qPkr5/1/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style media="screen" type="text/css">
    /* positioning */
    img.topLeft {position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;}
    img.topRight {position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0;}
    img.bottomLeft {position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0;}
    img.bottomRight {position: absolute; bottom: 0; right: 0;}

    /* element dimensions */
    div.work {background-color: #ddd; height:240px; position: relative; width:300px;}
    img {width:150px; height:120px; border:none;}
</style>
<body>
<div class="work">
    <a href="#"><img class="topLeft" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQFbb.jpg" /></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="topRight" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5OPs.jpg" /></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="bottomLeft" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/okxQz.jpg" /></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="bottomRight" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/4uPHw.jpg" /></a>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    // prevent click jump
    $('a').click(function() {
    return false;
    });

    // do work
    $('img').hover(
    function(){
        console.log( "mouseEnter" );
        var $that = $(this);
        $(this).parent().siblings('a').animate({opacity: 0},function() {
            $that.animate({
                width: "300px",
                height: "240px"
            });
        });
    },
    function(){
        console.log( "mouseLeave" );
        var $that = $(this);
        $(this).animate({
            width: "150px",
            height: "120px"
        }, 1500, function () {
            $that.parent().siblings('a').animate({opacity: 1});
        });
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Right, decided to have a play with this, it is not at all easy to achieve.

This is as far as I have got so far, still quite bugged, but it's a starting point.

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/NzcZH/**

**Initial Layout**

[image: Initial Layout]

**Fading**

[image: Fading]

**Growing**

[image: Growing]

**Fullsize**

[image: Fullsize]

---

Essentially, each image is hooked in to the `.mouseenter()`<sup>[(docs)](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/)</sup> / `.mouseleave()`<sup>[(docs)](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/)</sup> events, and an attempt is made to activate the required image, or deactivate it as required, if something is already going on, a primitive queue is created (which needs fixing).

Activation is how you had it, with a couple of modifications, it fades the opacity out, then grows the active image.  Deactivation is the reverse, shrink the active image back to the original, and then fade in (via opacity).

The changes to the model are mainly HTML/CSS necessities to do this sort of animation.

If you use straight `.fadeIn()`<sup>[(docs)](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/)</sup> / `.fadeOut()`<sup>[(docs)](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/)</sup> routines, these `.hide()`<sup>[(docs)](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)</sup> the images `(display: none;)` at the end, which removes them from the scene and ends up moving the non-faded, active image to the top corner, which breaks the animation.  Using opacity instead and absolute positioning of the images to hold them in place works better.  You could let them fade and hide, and reset the coordinates before animation instead, but that is no good if you wanted any overlap.

Ideally, the `z-index` should be altered on the images to keep the active item on top, this would allow parallel fading and growing, at present it is staged.

[I'm using the `.data()`<sup>[(docs)](http://api.jquery.com/data/)</sup> routine to store current state rather than a load of variables, bit neater.]

**HTML Structure**

```
<div class="work">
    <img id="tl" width="150" height="120" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQFbb.jpg" border="0" />
    <img id="tr" width="150" height="120" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5OPs.jpg" border="0" />
    <img id="bl" width="150" height="120" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/okxQz.jpg" border="0" />
    <img id="br" width="150" height="120" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/4uPHw.jpg" border="0" />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.work {
    padding: 5px 5px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 309px;
    height: 249px;
}

.active { border: 1px solid red; }

img { position: absolute; border: 1px dashed #aaa; }

#tl { top: 16; left: 16; }
#tr { top: 16; left: 171px; }
#bl { top: 141px; left: 16; }
#br { top: 141px; left: 171px; }
```

**jQuery Code**

```
var work = $('.work');
var workImages = work.find('img');
var growSpeed = 1500;
var fadeSpeed = 500;

work.data('changing', false).data('queue', false);

workImages.mouseenter(function() {
    var activeImg = workImages.filter('.active');

    if (activeImg.length == 0) {
        activate(this);
    }
}).mouseleave(function() {
    var activeImg = workImages.filter('.active');

    if (activeImg.length > 0) {
        deactivate();
    }
});

function activate(cImg) {
    if (work.data('changing') !== false) {
        work.data('queue', cImg);
        return;
    }

    var activeImg = workImages.filter('.active');

    if (activeImg.length != 0) {
        return;
    }

    work.data('changing', cImg);

    activeImg = $(cImg);

    activeImg.addClass('active');

    if (!activeImg.data('origPos')) {
        activeImg.data('origPos', { left: parseInt(activeImg.css('left')), top: parseInt(activeImg.css('top')) } );
    }

    workImages.stop();

    workImages.not(activeImg).animate({ opacity: 0 }, fadeSpeed, 'linear', function() {
        activeImg.animate({
            left: 16,
            top: 16,
            width: 307,
            height: 247
        }, growSpeed, 'linear', function() {
            work.data('changing', false);

            if (work.data('queue') !== false) {
                var queued = work.data('queue');
                work.data('queue', false);

                if (queued == 'deactivate') {
                    deactivate();
                } else if (queued != cImg) {
                    deactivate(queued);
                }
            }
        });
    });
}

function deactivate(cImg) {
    if (work.data('changing') !== false && work.data('changing') !== 'deactivate') {
        work.data('queue', 'deactivate');
        return;
    }

    if (cImg) {
        work.data('queue', cImg);
    }

    var activeImg = workImages.filter('.active');

    if (activeImg.length == 0) {
        return;
    }

    work.data('changing', 'deactivate');

    var origPos = activeImg.data('origPos');

    workImages.stop();

    activeImg.animate({
        left: origPos.left,
        top: origPos.top,
        width: 150,
        height: 120
    }, growSpeed, 'linear', function() {
        workImages.not(activeImg).animate({ opacity: 100 }, fadeSpeed, 'linear', function() {
            activeImg.removeClass('active');
            work.data('changing', false);

            if (work.data('queue') !== false) {
                var queued = work.data('queue');
                work.data('queue', false);
                activate(queued);
            }
        });
    });
}
```